# How can I a Coordinate Point by radius with another coordinate point and distance in Km?

Tags: java, android, coordinates, latitude-longitude, point

Im trying to cover a radius of, lets say 5 KM on the map. I have the coordinates of the middle of it.

I need a method to calculate and give me the coordinates of the points that are ON that circle.

**Explanation:**

[image]

(I need it to get coordinate points in a __Km radius from my server, If there's a better way to do that, please share. ty!)

I'll check whether if the coordinates are inside the circle or not like that:

(lan,lon) is a point.

```
if ((lat<x1 && lat>x2) && (lon<y1 && lon>y2))

    then the point is inside the circle.
```

**but then theres the problem that in some parts of the world it doesnt work...**

Im confused. how do I make a radar?

(android app)

Thanks!

Comment: There are an infinite number of points on the circle.  Which ones do you want?

Comment: I need them in the area where they are in the drawing.

Comment: also, now when I think about it, Im not sure this is going to work for me. Does anybody knows how to make a "radar" that will check whether a point is inside a circle or not?

Comment: yes you can say that but I need a better solution. updated the question.

Comment: You seem to have a wrong understanding of longitute and latitude as rectangular grid coordinates. Thats very wrong. Take a look at a globe. The nearer you are to the poles, the tighter the grid becomes, until right at the pole the distance between longitutes becomes *zero*. Determination of distances without taking these properties into account will be fruitless.

Comment: @Durandal, I'd say, that in radius of 5 km the error will be quite tolerable, unless it's the very pole.

Comment: @svz That would depend on your definiton of *tolerable*. Don't fool yourself into assuming you can just correct with a few factors and have it work almost globally - the difference in size of a long/lat "rectangle" compared between norway and italy is already quite huge, and those are both in europe. And europe is almost the smallest continent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are not too near to a pole you can approximate a smallish true circle on the surface of the Earth with an ellipse in the latitude-longitude space. The ellipse is a circle on the equator, but becomes more and more squished as you approach the poles.

Assuming the coordinates of the center of the circle you are interested in is `(lat0, lon0)` and the radius is `r = 5km`, set:

```
C = 40075.04km                - Earth circumference
A = 360*r/C                   - semi-minor in north-south direction 
B = 360*r/(C*cos(lat0))       - semi-major in east-west direction
```

Now the points `(lat,lon)` that within the ellipse fulfill this condition:

```
(lat-lat0)²/A² + (lon-lon0)²/B² < 1
```

In Java:

```
boolean pointInCircle(double lat0, double lon0, double r, double lat, double lon) {
    double C = 40075.04, A = 360*r/C, B = A/Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat0));
    return Math.pow((lat-lat0)/A, 2) + Math.pow((lon-lon0)/B, 2) < 1;
}
```

For more accurate results you can [compute the distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points?rq=1) between the center and the given point (typically using the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)), but the formulas are a lot more complex and can become expensive to compute if you have to calculate the distance for many points.

Comment: Thanks you so much! Would you please also write me how to check `(lat-lat0)²/A² + (lon-lon0)²/B² < 1` in PHP? - because Im downloading only the needed points. @Joni

Comment: Use `pow` instead of `Math.pow`, `cos` instead of `Math.cos`, and `deg2rad` instead of `Math.toRadians`.

Comment: And actually you were supposed to use the circumference, not the radius (fixed)..

Answer (score 1):

```
double dx = x - x0;
double dy = y - y0;
if (dx * dx + dy * dy < r * r) {
    // point (x, y) is inside the circle centered (x0, y0) with radius r
}
```